# ASP.NET iTextSharp PDF on iPad - Error

Tags: asp.net, ipad, pdf, itext

I'm developing an ASP.NET app that returns an iTextSharp (v4.1.6) PDF to the client via an ASP.NET Web API. This works fine in all desktop PC browsers I have tried, e.g. IE9, Firefox, Opera and Safari. Code below demonstrates the response that sends back the PDF.

The application also runs as a Web App on an Ipad 2 running IOS 6.1. When I return the PDF on the iPad I receive the following error.

**This page contains the following errors:
error on line 1 at column 1: Document is empty
error on line 1 at column 1: Encoding error**

This happens in any of the following on the iPad:  Web App mode, Safari or Google Chrome. The PDF itself does open and view fine when I email it from my desktop PC to my iPad, so it don't think there is a problem with the PDF itself but rather the way I am serving it to the client.

Any help would be much appreciated - I've been stuck on this for a quite a time!

API Code that generates PDF:

```
[HttpPost]
public string GetReport(JObject jObject)
{
    var context = HttpContext.Current;

    using (var ms = new MemoryStream())
    {
        MyPDF.Generate(ms); // Fills the Memory Stream with the iTextSharp PDF

        var data = ms.ToArray();
        var response = context.Response;
        response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);
        response.ContentType = "application/octlet-stream";
        response.AddHeader("content-length", data.Length.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture));
        response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment; filename=" + fileName.Replace(" ", string.Empty) + ".pdf");
        response.BinaryWrite(data);
        context.ApplicationInstance.CompleteRequest();
    }

    return string.Empty;
}
```